# Getting a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020059 error when trying to open Googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting this error when trying to restart the app. I have a fragment which contains a mapview and a recycler view:

```
06-17 02:13:09.174 25887-25887/com.map.rent.pickup E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.map.rent.pickup, PID: 25887
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.map.rent.pickup/com.map.rent.pickup.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020059
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020059
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2558)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2001)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1961)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.au.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):35)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.fu.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):12)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):32)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.df.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.dc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):11)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.t.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):29)
        at hq.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17455047@17.4.55 (040308-248795830):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zac.zaa(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zaa.onDelegateCreated(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.driptosinha.eataway.eataway.ui.PickupFragment.initGoogleMap(PickupFragment.java:302)
        at com.driptosinha.eataway.eataway.ui.PickupFragment.onCreateView(PickupFragment.java:147)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
        at android.app.Acti
```

It asks for some drawable resource but I am not calling anything like that. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".ui.RestaurantFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_map"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_list_map" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_pickup_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/restaurant_list_map"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.666"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the fragment:

```
public class PickupFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private Map<String, GeoPoint> userLocation;
    private GeoPoint geoPoint;
    private Context pickupContext;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private View pickupView;

public PickupFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        pickupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pickup, container, false);

        mMapView = pickupView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_list_map);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(pickupContext);
        bundle = getArguments();

        getUser();

        initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);

        return pickupView;
    }

private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // *** IMPORTANT ***
        // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
        // objects or sub-Bundles.
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        }
        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

This does not happen when I apply the changes, not when I run 'app'. Is there anyway I can reverse lookup the resource via the ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to build and do clean project once and then run the app if still not working

Go to File and then do Invalidate cache and Restart and then run it will work

Comment: Build -> Rebuild Project, worked for me